# How do I prevent STI shifter cables from blocking access to my Randoneering Bag or Handlebar bag?

Tags: touring, shifting, cable, randonneuring

I've got drop bars with Shimano Tiagra STI shifters and want to use a Rando Bag on my small front rack or a handlebar mount bag.  Currently the shift cables jut out between the drop bars and hit in to the sides of my bag and can't be bent around it.  I have to run the cables under the top flap of my rando bag to get them out of the way, but this makes it hard to access the contents of the bag on the road.

What can I do to prevent this cable from interfering with my rando bag that doesn't involve switching out my shifters?

Comment: This is a common problem.  The (I think -- would have to check) brake cables arc out from the brifters and pass right through the area where one would want to mount a handlebar bag.  Don't know of any solution other than to get some different brifters or do without the bag.

Comment: No, he's right, it is the shift cables that arc out, not the brake cables.

Comment: It should be mentioned that many regard a bar bag to be a poor choice, from the standpoint of bike stability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is probably to move to either a different shifter setup like newer shimano 105/ultegra or SRAM (with cable routing under the handlebars) or to a barend setup like most randos employ. I know this isn't your preferred solution, but it's probably the easiest and most effective. If you mess with the routing/length on your shift cables, you're going to start experiencing shift slipping and improper shifting.

Comment: How much more modern?  The 10 speed shifters I got on my bike I purchased new 2 months ago are not modern enough?  Can you give a recommendation?

Comment: Looking at images of Shimano STI shifters on amazon, the Tiagra level shifter has the brake cable coming out the side. Upgrading to the 105 or higher has both the brake and shift cable that run under your handlebar tape.

Comment: Campagnolo shifters also put both cables under the bar, but then you need to swap more stuff out, or use a Jtek Shiftmate or similar.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that someone has come up with a solution to use vbrake noodles to re-route the STI shifter cables with some success.

http://thecrazyrandonneur.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/how-to-have-a-large-handlebar-bag-with-sti-shifters/

Answer (score 1):

[Nokon Cables](http://www.nokon.com/) can be used to route your derailer cable under the bar tape. They still may stick out a bit.

http://weightweenies.starbike.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=65639&view=next